# Tools for Data Driven and Keyword driven tests in selenium with python?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to selenium and python, I was watching some videos on data driven and keyword driven tests, the instructor was using TestNG with selenium and

I was wondering are there any tools similar to TestNG but that I can write my scripts in python?

Any suggestions on video tutorials for selenium with python?